# Bash Script to Copy Folders by first character

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

I'm a newbie to ubuntu/Linux, and just got my first bash script to execute.

I'm trying to copy and organize my music collection from driveA to driveB.

driveA has all my artists folders (e.g Adele, Brian, Bob Marley, Cassie) the path to this /media/myMusic

in driveB i have created folders A, B, C and the path to those is /media/orderedMusic

All artist folders whose first character is A or B or C in driveA will be copied to respective folders in driveB i.e. Adele would be copied to /media/orderedMusic/A,
Brian and Bob Marley would be copied to /media/orderedMusic/B and so on.

here is what i have so far, help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

folder1=/media/myMusic
folder2=/media/orderedMusic

for dir in $folder1
do
  if []
  then
    cp
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

folder1=/media/myMusic
folder2=/media/orderedMusic

cd "$folder1" && {
  for artist in *; do
    dest=$folder2/${artist:0:1}
    mkdir -p "$dest"
    cp -rp "$artist" "$dest"
  done
}
```

Note that if you are on a case-sensitive filesystem and have artist names that aren't capitalized, you will get separate folders in the destination tree for the two cases.. e.g. an "A" folder and an "a" folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could use substring extraction: `${string:start_index:length}`:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder1=/media/myMusic
folder2=/media/orderedMusic

for dir in "$folder1/*"
do
    initial=${dir:0:1}
    src="$folder1/$dir"
    dest="$folder2/$initial"
    # test if the destination directory exists
    if [ ! -d "$dest" ]
    then
        mkdir $dest
    fi
    cp -r $src $dest
done
```

Also you could use string index as you need only the first one character in a string.
For more details, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: `for dir in $folder1` doesn't iterate over the contents of the directory.

Comment: so i get an error cp: cannot stat `/media/myMusic//media/orderedMusic ': No such file or directory i think its looking for a folder with just the 1st character as the name maybe?

Comment: @MarkReed Thank you very much for pointing this out. I copied those lines directly from the OP and didn't check much about it... Thank you again :)

Comment: @Sam-i-Am Sorry for my mistake.. Please see Mark's comment and my edited answer.